# I can't create a database with symfony 5 ( An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver )

Tags: php, mysql, symfony5

I can't create a database with the command "php bin/console doctrine:database:create" I have this error getting [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg8XU.png). Here is my .env file `

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=de5960e51dfbd4c84561210d153ed8c3
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> symfony/webapp-pack ###
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default?auto_setup=0
###< symfony/webapp-pack ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/test?serverVersion=5.7"
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=14&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/messenger ###
# Choose one of the transports below
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/messages
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=redis://localhost:6379/messages
###< symfony/messenger ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
# MAILER_DSN=null://null
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

`
Also the address of my localhost on phpmyadmin is : localhost:8080
and the address of my localhost on symfony is: localhost:8000 with the command : php -S localhost:8000 -t public

I've tried everything, I need help please.

I use wampserver, I have symfony 5 & php8.

Here is the default MySQL line in my .env file : [mysql line default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1RoV.png)

And here is the change I made : [mysql line modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYcCj.png)

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: You would be way better off creating a Virtual Host for this project and running it through a proper Apache/PHP environment. Yu will fond moving it to a live server easier too later

Comment: the problem is resolved, thank you.

Comment: @KevinJM can you please add an answer to be more helpful. what was the problem? how did you fix it?